# How to transfer select value to php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to display the photos according to the album selected. But, I don't want to post the page, I want to just change the div.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function replaceContent(divName, contentS) {
                 document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = <?php echo get_pictures_from_album($fb, $albums, contentS); ?>;
            }
        </script>
```

And this is the select tag that invokes it:

```
<select name="album" size= "1" style="width:210;" onchange="replaceContent('photos', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <?php get_albums_select_list($albums); ?>
        </select>

        <div id = "photos">
            <?php echo get_profile_pictures($fb, $albums); ?>
        </div>
```

I understand from a reading that I have done that the problem might be connected to javascript Vs php variable types.

Please advise.

Comment: The problem connected to the fundamental principle unknown to you yet: PHP is running on the server but JavaScript is running thousands miles from it, on the client.

Comment: is it possible to execute php code without reloading the page or using some sort of asynchronous execution like AJAX?

Comment: I know server-client architecture thank you... I just strugle with syntax issues. I wanted it to work like AJAX. So only the relevant div will refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for an AJax call to an PHP script that retrives the data for the appropriate album selected and **THEN** update the div with the callback function.
[Ajax + PHP basics](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html)

Comment: Hey Gal, are you coming from PHP background?  You might want to take a look at http://mootools.net/.  When i started learning Javascript coming from php mootools made it really easy to understand and use its framework.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not possible because PHP code runs ***before*** (on the server because PHP is server-side language) javascript code.

[You will have to resort ot AJAX for that.](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Clientside and Serverside Code here. The function replaceContent is called after the page (and the php code) was loaded. You would need an Ajax Call for that if you need more information about that:

[Ajax Tutorials on Google](http://www.google.ch/#hl=en&biw=1209&bih=771&q=Ajax+javascript+php+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&fp=528fdf9e8a0b759a)